# grep multiple patterns Or condition on grouping data

Tags: r

I have a data grouped data,

```
df <- data.frame(group_id= c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4),
                words = c("beach", "sand", "trip", "warm","travel", "water","beach","sand", "trees"),
                 ID = c("vacation", "vacation", "vacation", "vacation", "meeting","vacation","meeting","onduty", "hiking"))
```

The `group_id` is groups of `ID` column. Now I want to check certain patterns ("beach" or "warm" or "sand") for each group, and print the matching pattern in separate column and matches 0 (no match) or 1 (yes macth) in separate column.

Expected :

```
  id  words       ID           pattern Match
1  1  beach vacation Beach, sand, warm 1
2  1   sand vacation Beach, sand, warm 1
3  1   trip vacation Beach, sand, warm 1
4  1   warm vacation Beach, sand, warm 1
5  2 travel  meeting Beach             1
6  1  water vacation Beach, sand, warm 1
7  2  beach  meeting Beach             1
8  3   sand   onduty sand              1
9  4  trees  hiking  0                 0
```

Comment: Please know what you want when asking a question. Otherwise, you can open a new question.

Comment: Sorry. I edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `dplyr` `grep` to get the desired result.
Below is the code:

```
library(dplyr) 

pattern <- c("Beach", "sand", "warm")
df <- data.frame(group_id= c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4),
                 words = c("beach", "sand", "trip", "warm","travel", "water","beach","sand", "trees"),
                 ID = c("vacation", "vacation", "vacation", "vacation", "meeting","vacation","meeting","onduty", "hiking"))

x <- df %>%
  group_by(group_id) %>%
  summarise(words = paste(words, collapse = " "))
y <- sapply(pattern, function(d) grep(paste0("\\b",d,"\\b"),x$words , ignore.case = T))
y <- setNames(unlist(y, use.names=F),rep(names(y), lengths(y)))
y <- data.frame(Match_pattern =names(y), group_id=y, row.names=NULL)
y <- y %>%
  group_by(group_id) %>%
  summarise(Match_pattern = paste(Match_pattern, collapse = ", "))

out <- merge(df, y, by = "group_id", all.x = T)
out$N <- ifelse(is.na(out$Match_pattern), 0, 1)

> out
  group_id  words       ID     Match_pattern N
1        1   sand vacation Beach, sand, warm 1
2        1   trip vacation Beach, sand, warm 1
3        1   warm vacation Beach, sand, warm 1
4        1  beach vacation Beach, sand, warm 1
5        1  water vacation Beach, sand, warm 1
6        2  beach  meeting             Beach 1
7        2 travel  meeting             Beach 1
8        3   sand   onduty              sand 1
9        4  trees   hiking              <NA> 0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ids <- df$ID[ grepl("^(beach|warm|sand)$",df$words) ]

df[df$ID %in% ids,]

#  group_id  words       ID
#1        1  beach vacation
#2        1   sand vacation
#3        1   trip vacation
#4        1   warm vacation
#5        2 travel  meeting
#6        1  water vacation
#7        2  beach  meeting
#8        3   sand   onduty
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to add the matched patterns in a separate column?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following. Find `unique` values for `group_id` that associate with the key `words`. Subset `df` using `[]`.

```
df[df$group_id %in% unique(df$group_id[df$words %in% c('beach', 'sand', 'warm')]),]

  group_id  words       ID
1        1  beach vacation
2        1   sand vacation
3        1   trip vacation
4        1   warm vacation
5        2 travel  meeting
6        1  water vacation
7        2  beach  meeting
8        3   sand   onduty
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `sqldf`:
First select the `group_id` having `words` `('beach','sand','warm')` and then select all the values from these `group_id`.

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("select * from df where group_id IN(select group_id from df where words IN ('beach','sand','warm'))")
```

Output:

```
    group_id  words   ID
1        1  beach vacation
2        1   sand vacation
3        1   trip vacation
4        1   warm vacation
5        2 travel  meeting
6        1  water vacation
7        2  beach  meeting
8        3   sand   onduty
```